# I want the number of entry according to date_collected hand having complete no

Tags: php, mysqli

This is my table structure:

```
id  customer  date_received  completed  date_collected

18  14       2018-08-18       no        2018-08-23
19  15       2018-08-18       no        2018-08-23
24  18       2018-08-18       no        2018-08-21
25  17       2018-08-10       Yes       2018-08-16
26  19       2018-08-18       Yes       2018-08-23
27  20       2018-08-17       Yes       2018-08-22
```

My query :

```
SELECT COUNT(date_collected) FROM `order`
WHERE `date_collected`="2018-09-05" AND `completed`='No'
```

I want the number of entry by date collected only complete (no). like date_collected is 2018-08-23 number of count of complete no is 2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10599789/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/10395444/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/16584549/2943403

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28726329/2943403

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mySQL count only returning one result unless using group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40503132/mysql-count-only-returning-one-result-unless-using-group-by)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like below to meet your requirement...

```
SELECT *, COUNT(`date_collected`) AS not_collected_count
FROM `your_table` 
WHERE `completed` = 'no' 
GROUP BY `date_collected`;
```

`GROUP BY` will help to group similar dates

`COUNT` will help to get the number of entries in that date

Here is a [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/53abc/5)

Comment: not_collected_count
2
1
2
1
2
1
3
1
2
1
1
1
4
1
i got this output but i also want the respective date

Comment: what respective date? is it `date_collected`

Comment: All columns shown in your table are also showing in the above query.